# How do I update the version of R used by R.Net (RdotNet) so it uses my current R version

Tags: r

Every time I upgrade to the next version of R I have a similar problem, R.Net tries to use the previous version of R I had installed.  I thought I had the solution, I update the R_HOME environment variable to point to the new version, also update the PATH environment variable by replacing the previous version with the newer version.  And reboot my server.  This has worked previously when I have upgraded R.Net.

This time I have moved from R 3.4.2 to R 3.4.3.  I have modified my environment variables, but R.Net still will only look for R 3.4.2 and so everything is broken.   When I type

```
R.Evaluate("R.Version()").AsCharacter()
```

I get the following, it is still pointing to R 3.4.2 which is not longer installed on my machine.

```
Length = 14; RObjectType = CharacterVector
[0]: "x86_64-w64-mingw32"
[1]: "x86_64"
[2]: "mingw32"
[3]: "x86_64, mingw32"
[4]: ""
[5]: "3"
[6]: "4.2"
[7]: "2017"
[8]: "09"
[9]: "28"
[10]: "73368"
[11]: "R"
[12]: "R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)"
[13]: "Short Summer"
```

How do I update R.Net so that it uses R version 3.4.3, which is the version I have installed on my computer?  Where is it getting the information to use R version 3.4.2?

Answer (score 0):

Situation resolved.  An unrelated piece of code was setting the version to 3.4.2 for a different r engine, which was causing my code to also use that version number